# How to Select all options in a dropdown by default using <Option Value=""> in chrome?

Tags: html, html-select

Here is the code I am having issues with:

```
<select name="webmenu" id="filter_option" style="width: 175px; "  onchange="searchTree($(this).val());">
    <option value="">--View All--</option> 
    <option value="Tree">Tree</option>
    <option value="Dog Approval">Dog Approval</option>
    <option value="Cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="Sky">Sky</option>
```

I have an issue with the dropdown in that when I select this: `<option value="">--View All--</option>` in chrome the list does not load all default values when this option is selected.

When I go into chrome inspector and look at the line: `<option value="">--View All--</option>` the option value looks like this: `<option>--View All--</option>`

Why is it stripping out the `value=""` part of the code?

Answer (score 0):

without the code ot link to that site I cannot guess what exactly is happening at your side.

but answering the question from the title…

you can only select multiple options if the attribute `multiple` is present in the tag `select`. then to make an `option` tag selected it needs the attribute `selected`.
so to select all options, all `option` tags need an attribute `selected`.

read up: [select](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_select.asp), [multiple](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_select_multiple.asp), [option](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_option.asp)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>

<select size="5" multiple>
<option selected value="1">1</option>
<option selected value="2">2</option>
<option selected value="3">3</option>
<option selected value="4">4</option>
<option selected value="5">5</option>
</select>

</body></html>
```

if you can maybe add your problem to the above playground and a solution might be found through that.